# Sending JWT automatically when published not working in angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

I have an angular 7 application. And I'm sending my `JWT` with every request. **In my local, it is working**. But, when I published to server, it isn't working. I'm using `auth0` library for sending JWT automatically. What can be the reason of this?

**related part of my app.module.ts**

```
import { JwtModule } from '@auth0/angular-jwt';

@NgModule({
  imports: [    
   JwtModule.forRoot({
      config: {
        tokenGetter: tokenGetter,
        whitelistedDomains: [new RegExp('[\s\S]*')] as RegExp[],
        blacklistedRoutes: []
      }
    })]
})
```